# Connect dots with splines

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I smooth the edges in line plot? I can do I line plot like this:

```
data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(22,23,21,25,23,24,20,27,22,24))
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line(colour='forestgreen')
```

However, I don't like sharp edges. Is there a way to draw a line through those points so that the line is smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(splines)
library(gridExtra)

dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(22,23,21,25,23,24,20,27,22,24))

plot.new() # have to do this unfortunately
res <- xspline(dat$x, dat$y, -0.25, draw=FALSE)

gg1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line(colour='forestgreen') +
  geom_point()

gg2 <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=res$x, y=res$y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(data=dat, aes(x, y), size=1) +
  geom_line(color="blue")

grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, ncol=1)
```

[image]

This is using `xspline` to do the interpolation. Lookup the function to see what tweaking the `-0.25` parameter (range is `-1` to `1`) will do.

Comment: It works. Now I just need to figure out a way to deal with missing values. I've got many time series with missing values in various places. I guess I just need to split the time series into different blocks so that they don't contain missing values and calculate splines for each block. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're willing to use the github/devtools version of ggplot2 I wrapped this into a package https://github.com/hrbrmstr/gggaldu as well (said pkg is going to have more ggplot2 extensions)

Comment: I think this would be a useful package. However, I have problem installing it.  `Error : package 'ggplot2' 1.0.1 was found, but >= 1.0.1.9003 is required by 'ggalt'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggalt'
* removing 'ggalt'
Error: Command failed (1)`. But thanks for your answer anyway. With a little bit of coding I'll get what I need from the graph.

Comment: As the pkg says in the readme you have to use the development version of ggplot2. Not for the timid. Once the new ggplot2 is on CRAN this package will be as well.