# Smoothing Lines in ggplot between all data point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame similar to this example

```
SqMt <- "Sex Sq..Meters PDXTotalFreqStpy 
    1          M        129          22         
    2          M        129          0         
    3          M        129          1         
    4          F        129          35         
    5          F        129          42         
    6          F        129          5         
    7          M        557          20         
    8          M        557          0         
    9          M        557          15         
    10         F        557          39         
    11         F        557          0         
    12         F        557          0         
    13         M        1208         33         
    14         M        1208         26         
    15         M        1208         3         
    16         F        1208         7         
    17         F        1208         0         
    18         F        1208         8         
    19         M        604          68         
    20         M        604          0         
    21         M        604          0         
    22         F        604          0         
    23         F        604          0         
    24         F        604          0"

Data <- read.table(text=SqMt, header = TRUE)
```

I want to show the average `PDXTotalFreqStpy` for each `Sq..Meters` organized by `Sex`. This is what I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x=Sq..Meters, y=PDXTotalFreqStpy)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", aes(group=Sex,color=Sex))
```

How do I get these lines smoothed out so that they are not jagged and instead, nice and curvy and go through all the data points? I have seen things on spline, but I have not gotten those to work?

Comment: Can you show what you tried with spline? That's an acceptable approach to obtaining a smoothed line. Any interpolation method will probably help achieve what you want.

Comment: Isn't there a "geom_smooth" or some such? Your requirement that they "go through all the data points" is not going to be met, however. That would require an n-th degree polynomial fit which would end up being extremely messy. You should instead expect that they would be "_reasonably_ close to _most_ of the data points".

Comment: @busybear - I suppose what I am trying to achieve was the same thing this person was trying to achieve: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447652/connect-dots-with-splines]. This did not work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @42- Thank you for this insight! So is it not possible to simply connect all the points with a less jagged line? This post is asking the same question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447652/connect-dots-with-splines]

Comment: Look at geom_path for connections, but I don't know if it has a "round corners" option. Look for a cubic spline geom function, perhaps geom_smooth?

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
library(dplyr)

# increase n if the result is not smooth enough
# (for this example, n = 50 looks sufficient to me)
n = 50

# manipulate data to calculate the mean for each sex at each x-value
# before passing the result to ggplot()
Data %>%
  group_by(Sex, x = Sq..Meters) %>%
  summarise(y = mean(PDXTotalFreqStpy)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = Sex)) +

  # optional: show point locations for reference
  geom_point() +

  # optional: show original lines for reference
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +

  # further data manipulation to calculate values for smoothed spline
  geom_line(data = . %>%
              group_by(Sex) %>%
              summarise(x1 = list(spline(x, y, n)[["x"]]),
                        y1 = list(spline(x, y, n)[["y"]])) %>%
              tidyr::unnest(),
            aes(x = x1, y = y1))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Oh wow okay, this is what I have been sort of achieving but I wasn't happy with it because of the extreme curves - what I'm trying to achieve is simply smoothing out the jagged edged straight lines connecting my dots. Do you know why the curves are dipping into the negatives and then going way up in the opposite direction? I suppose what I'm trying to do is what this person was asking in this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447652/connect-dots-with-splines].